# Script that launches commands on two Terminals

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I need to do a `.command` file script/batch. Launching it (double-click) it has to to those things:

1. Open a terminal window (A)
2. Launching a command that open the folder where the file is (maybe this `cd "dirname "$0""`)
3. Launch a command
4. Open a terminal window (B)
5. Launching same command at point 2
6. Launch a command

Answer (score 0):

Given that you explicitly want to create terminal windows, consider creating an *application* using *AppleScript*:

- Open `Script Editor` (up to 10.9, `AppleScript Editor`)
- Paste the code below.
- Save as an *application* (via the pop-up list in the `Save As` dialog) to the desired folder.

```applescript
# Determine the folder in which this app is located.
set thisFolder to do shell script "dirname " & quoted form of POSIX path of (path to me)

# Sample commands to execute in the new windows.
set cmds to {"date", "echo $$"}

tell application "Terminal"
    # Create 2 new windows, change to the
    # this app's folder, and execute the respective command.
    repeat with i from 1 to 2
        do script "cd " & quoted form of thisFolder & "; " & item i of cmds
    end repeat
    # Activate Terminal.app
    activate
end tell
```

The reason that I recommend using an *application* over a `*.command` file is that the latter would *itself* open in a Terminal window first, before creating the desired windows, which is visually disruptive (and, depending on your Terminal.app preferences, may leave the extra window open).

Alternatively, you could turn that into a virtue and use the `*.command` file's own window as your 1st terminal window, and only create *one* additional one.